# In Visual Studio's Designer, why don't any images show up in the Select Resource window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resources, embedded-resource

[image: Why no images show up]

I got here by clicking on a `Button` on my `Form` in the designer, going to the Properties window, finding the Image property, and hitting the `...` button that appears to the right of the textbox.

If I open up the Properties\Resources.resx file in the designer, I see all the images in my project, yet I cannot view them in this list. I suppose I could import the images I want from a directory, but then I would have duplicates.

How can I select from images in the resource file from this dialog? How can I get them to appear? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably click the `Import` button first, and than add the images. This will add them to the resource folder. You should do this from visual studio, not via the explorer

Comment: I've inherited this project. The images are already in the resx file. Are you suggesting that I make copies of all the images, remove them all, and then re-add them through this window?

Comment: Yes I'd try that, that helped for me

Comment: I have the same problem. Importing images from Select Resource window indeed adds them to Properties\Resources.resx, and the image itself is at first visible in Select Resorce window, but after clicking OK, the PictureBox is not updated (Image value is still "(none)") and when opening Select Resource again (via choosing image for the picture box), the newly added image does not show up anymore. It just shows dark gray background when I select it from the list.

Comment: I have to add that it seems to work in one project, but does not work in another. I was not able to find any reason for this so far. I do the steps in exactly the same order, but it only seems to work for a newly created project, but not for my other existing projects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it was a simple answer.  I have multiple projects in my solution, and consolidate my common resources in a separate assembly.  The resources must be in the same project (assembly) in order to be accessed by the designer of whatever control you're using that wants to use the image.  Otherwise you have to get the images at runtime.